# PHP and android

Tags: php, replace, find

Here if i try to replace a string v= by v=9 the next line will append with it and next line deleted for each inserts.

```
 $manifile = 'sample.txt';
 $nvercode =2;
 $str="v=";
 $no = findlineNo($manifile,$str);
 echo $no;
 $update = "v=9";
 $txt1 = file($manifile);
 $content = file_get_contents($manifile);
 $newcontent = str_replace($txt1[$no-1],$update, $content);
 file_put_contents($manifile,$newcontent);
```

How do i replace a string without alter other lines...Can any one help me please..

Comment: not clear your question

Comment: what exactly are you even trying to do?